# MediaStore Audio Column DATA Is Deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, mediastore

Hello guys i am trying to get the absolute path of audio file in android `api level 29 i.e, Q` but the problem is that **DATA is `deprecated`** so how to resolve this problem and also using the `absolute path (e.x : storage/sdcard/music.mp3)` we can get the embedded picture to that audio but in content uri (`content://`) that we can get using the `_ID Column` by appending the id of the file.But if we are not able to to get the absolute path then how to play an audio file using `content://` *Uri* ?
The previous codes that i am using is :

```
public ArrayList<Song> FolderFilesList(Context context, String FolderPath) {
      //folder-exclude-sub-folders

        ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();

  String[] columns = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,

    };


        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ?      AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " NOT LIKE ? ";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                "%" + FolderPath + "%",
                "%" + FolderPath + "/%/%"
        };

        Cursor cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns(), selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Song song = new Song(
                         cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)),
                        cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)),
                        cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK)),
                        cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
                );

                //File f = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                // if (f.isFile() && f.exists()) {
                songs.add(song);
                //}
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return songs;
    }
```

Comment: `But if we are not able to to get the absolute path then how can this also be solved ? `. Yes you cannot get the absoluthe path under Q. And it is unclear what you wanna solve.

Comment: So how to play audio files in android Q using MediaPlayer please give any solution.Android Developer site say use openFileDescriptor but how to do this i am not understanding.

Comment: @blackapps, there you go again, no solutions or pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get the absolute path now but you can get content uri and using that content uri means (`content://`) and use it to write file in your cache directory of your package folder using the below code :

```
String filePath = new File(resolver.openFileDescriptor(contentUri, "r");
```

And then use InputStream and OutputStream to store it in cache directory and use this filePath to as a File.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this line in application in the Manifest file

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```